# Cypress - Change site where the tests are run when starting them

Tags: cypress

I'm unsure the title is quite clear so allow me to elaborate.

Say I have 4 servers with the same content, and I write a test case that checks a functionality on that page, hardcoding `cy.visit('google.com');`.

But I want to use this same test for all 4 servers since they are the same. Is there a way to change what page this test will work on that isn't just changing the `cy.visit()` content?

The end objective is to have these tests uploaded to GitHub so anyone can run them with the server they need, I'm hoping that they could do this by simple running the test selecting the server they want, not having to edit the code each time

Answer (score 3):

You will need to `cy.visit()` the resolved IP of each of the servers.

For example, from a terminal `ping google.com` gives you resolved IP of `142.250.76.110`, so you can write a test like this

```js
cy.visit('https://142.250.76.110');
cy.get('input[aria-label="Google Search"]')  // passes
```

Maybe the servers you want to reach are on corporate network with common IP except for the last number, or maybe all `http://localhost:<port>` with different port numbers.

In any case, just visit each is a data-driven fashion:

```js
const server = ['192.168.1.01', '192.168.1.02', '192.168.1.03', '192.168.1.04']

servers.forEach(ip => {
  it(`tests server "${ip}`, () => {
    cy.visit(`https://${ip}`)
    ...
  })
})
```

---

After your edit...

To run tests for a selected server, one way might be to set up a "shell" test for each server. You can import the tests into the shell to run them.

For example,

```js
// run-server-2.cy.js

Cypress.config('baseUrl', '192.168.1.02')

require('spec1.cy.js')    // uses cy.visit('/') to access baseUrl set above
require('spec2.cy.js')
require('spec3.cy.js')
...
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't what I'm looking for. 

I need a way for someone to run a test indicating in the run command what server they would like to choose, whether this is them typing out a link or them selecting an option (say I have hardcoded the addresses in an Array, as you did) - but I can't have it so it runs the test on every server, I need only to run the test on one server.

This would be even better if I can run a suite of tests off 1 command on 1 server only

Comment: In the run command, it's just a simple command-line flag `--config baseUrl=192.168.1.02`. You said ***simple running the test selecting the server they want***.

Comment: After your edit - If I understood you correctly what you mean, the easiest way is to create a shell for each server - say server 1 is run-server-1.cy.js / server 2 run-server-2.cy.js / etc. And then in each of these require each of the tests?

Comment: Originally the question read (to me) that you were testing every server. I added the **After your edit** section after your edit.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what you can do. If you prefer per-server scripts in `package.json` the the `--config` option would suit you better.

Comment: The command-line or script example is here [Overriding Individual Options](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Overriding-Individual-Options).

Comment: Ok, the issue I'm having with using ```require()``` is that it doesn't output anything to indicate what stage fails and what doesn't in the cypress IDE. So when the tests are running so I don't know what stage the test is on, so I don't know when there is an error